# Syntax Error when saving file path to variable

Tags: python-3.x, path, syntax-error

I am trying to save a path file to a variable. It is part of a larger set of code. I keep getting a syntax error , but it is not obvious as to why. Whenever I take the code and run it separately in a different cell in jupyter notebook it works fine. It's just when I run it as part of the bigger code set that I get a syntax error.

Anyone have any idea why? I am unable to share my entire code as it contains some confidential details.

**below is the code I run as part of the larger script**

`path = r"C:\Users\O34639\Desktop\Python_Scripts\SSI.xlsx"`

**I receive the error below**

```
File "<ipython-input-193-2b5bd969f401>", line 51 
path = r"C:\Users\O34639\Desktop\Python_Scripts\SSI.xlsx" 
^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**when I run the code on it's own cell it works properly no issues, but I have no idea why it's not working when running it as part of the bigger script**

**I've tried using the escape \ and getting rid of the r character, but I still get the same message**

Comment: It's likely a problem on the line above this. Probably a missing `)`.

Comment: Please include the rest of your source code in your question, or else we cannot help you.